# append or remove html code based on checkbox status

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to make a javascript function that will append html code to a div if a checkbox is checked or it will remove the last elements if the checkbox is unchecked. I have almost got it to work. When i check a checkbox html code is added as i want but if i select another one it adds my appended code 2 more times instead of one more time.

I write my code down here

```
function myEvent(control) {
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length+1;
  var i = 0;
  if(!control.checked) {
    $(".myInputs .inputgroup").last().remove();
    $(".myInputs .inputgroup").last().remove();
  }
  for(i = 1; i < checkboxes; i++) {
    $(".myInputs").append("<div class=\"inputgroup col-1\"><label for=\"name"+i+"\">Item Name:</label><input type=\"text\" name=\"name[]\" id=\"name"+i+"\"></div><div class=\"inputgroup col-3\"><label for=\"displayid"+i+"\">Item Displayid:</label><input type=\"text\" name=\"displayid[]\" id=\"displayid"+i+"\"></div>");
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a runnable snippet?

Comment: Im trying to post a snippet but for some reason the code wont run in pastebin or jsfiddle. I tells me function is undefined in codepen atleast. No idea why i get that error... It was working earlier on codepen but now it gives me error and keeps crashing.

Comment: https://codepen.io/tok124/pen/WNbJEwG

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use to **each function** for checking how many checkbox is checked and append results as checked. And second method use for checking **on change event** for **append/remove** result according to checkbox.
I hope this below snippet will help you lot.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  /*After page load then check how many checbox is checked and then append results*/ 
  $('.checktable input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(i,h){
    var checkboxId = $(this).attr('id');
    $(".myInputs").append("<tr class=\"remove_"+checkboxId+"\"><td><label for=\"name_"+checkboxId+"\">Item Name:</label></td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"name[]\" id=\"name_"+checkboxId+"\"></td></tr>"+
      "<tr class=\"remove_"+checkboxId+"\"><td><label for=\"displayid_"+checkboxId+"\">Item Displayid:</label></td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"displayid[]\" id=\"displayid_"+checkboxId+"\"></td></tr>");
  });

  /*When change then event will fire*/
  $('.checktable input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(){
    var checkboxId = $(this).attr('id');
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $(".myInputs").append("<tr class=\"remove_"+checkboxId+"\"><td><label for=\"name_"+checkboxId+"\">Item Name:</label></td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"name[]\" id=\"name_"+checkboxId+"\"></td></tr>"+
      "<tr class=\"remove_"+checkboxId+"\"><td><label for=\"displayid_"+checkboxId+"\">Item Displayid:</label></td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"displayid[]\" id=\"displayid_"+checkboxId+"\"></td></tr>");
    }else{
      $('.remove_'+checkboxId).remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inputgroup col-1">
  <table class="checktable" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td><label for="headitem">Head:</label></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="inventorytype[]" id="headitem" checked></td>
      <td><label for="shoulderitem">Shoulder:</label></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="3" name="inventorytype[]" id="shoulderitem"></td>
      <td><label for="chestitem">Chest:</label></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="5" name="inventorytype[]" id="chestitem"></td>
      <td><label for="waistitem">Waist:</label></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="6" name="inventorytype[]" id="waistitem" checked></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="legsitem">Legs:</label></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="7" name="inventorytype[]" id="legsitem"></td>
      <td><label for="feetitem">Feet:</label></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="8" name="inventorytype[]" id="feetitem"></td>
      <td><label for="wristitem">Wrist:</label></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="9" name="inventorytype[]" id="wristitem"></td>
      <td><label for="glovesitem">Gloves:</label></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="10" name="inventorytype[]" id="glovesitem"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="neckitem">Neck:</label></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="2" name="inventorytype[]" id="neckitem"></td>
      <td><label for="shirtitem">Shirt:</label></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="4" name="inventorytype[]" id="shirtitem"></td>
      <td><label for="fingeritem">Finger:</label></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="11" name="inventorytype[]" id="fingeritem"></td>
      <td><label for="trinketitem">Trinket</label></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="12" name="inventorytype[]" id="trinketitem"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="shielditem">Shield:</label></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="14" name="inventorytype[]" id="shielditem"></td>
      <td><label for="cloakitem">Cloak:</label></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="16" name="inventorytype[]" id="cloakitem"></td>
      <td><label for="tabarditem">Tabard:</label></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="19" name="inventorytype[]" id="tabarditem"></td>
      <td><label for="relicitem">Relic</label></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="28" name="inventorytype[]" id="relicitem"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<br>

<div class="col-1">
  <table class="myInputs" border="0">
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: this is the perfect one to achieve the requirements exactly (y)

Answer (score 3):

So ... you run myEvent when a checkbox is checked?  The first time, one checkbox is checked and the for loop runs once.  The second time, the second checkbox is checked and the for loop runs twice.

The function myEvent receives a reference to the checkbox ("control") so there is no need to search for it in the function.  You can use `if control.checked == true` to test if you should add the new html or remove it.  Hmm, seems you already do that for testing whether to remove the html ... just make an "else" for the "adding" code and remove the "for".

Answer (score 2):

I see you're very close to the result you just need add following line before your for loop:

```
$(".myInputs").html('');
for(i = 1; i < checkboxes; i++) {
```

As you're looping through all checked checkbox and appending the HTML to result, so before doing that you need to make the result div blank. here is the updated fiddle:

https://codepen.io/prashant-shukla-the-vuer/pen/GRgdvrR

Comment: Thank you this works better but if i have written anything in the input before i check another checkbox the text in the inputs will be removed. So is there anyway to prevent making the div blank and still get the same result?

Comment: okay for that you can just remove the for loop, as you want append/remove HTML as per the condition if current checkbox is checked or unchecked. so I've updated the fiddle: https://codepen.io/prashant-shukla-the-vuer/pen/GRgdvrR

Comment: `@prashant` From this **$('.myInputs').html(' ')** method to previous append and filled value will remove so we need to define separate function for append/remove.